# Create a list of figures, equations and other items

Tags: views, entities, nodes

I run a website that is like an electronic book http://www.pveducation.org Presently there are equations, images, mini-calculators that are included in the body of each page. How do I get Drupal to automatically create a list of links to,for example, the equations?  I also thought of making the equations a Content Type and use Views to make a page of all the equations but then I can't figure out how to use the new type in the body of each page. Should I use entities instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case for views.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you need to do the following:

1. create a block in views (see http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/create-block-display)
2. assign that block to the region you want it to appear in your default theme (Structure -> Blocks), see https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block

You can also restrict the pages on which the block should appear.

Comment: I understand how to use the view, which would have a list of equations, but I need the individual equations to be inserted in the body of the text:
blah blah blah blah
equation
blah blah blah blah

I this possible in Drupal? Wouldn't it mean putting a block inside a field?

Comment: I would add the equations to individual nodes, using wiris ( http://www.wiris.com/en/solutions/drupal) or something similar. You might want to clarify in your question that you are looking for a way to display equations.

Comment: I followed your suggestions for Views and then used [node embed](https://drupal.org/project/node_embed‎) to put the equation on the page. Views is very powerful but takes a while to learn so thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The equations were just an example but also thanks for the WIRIS link.